# How do I make a loss function for a Weibull Distribution model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, loss-function, weibull, log-likelihood

I want to make a model using TensorFlow which will return the 2 characteristics of a Weibull distribution. In order to make it I need to create a loss function which fits the Weibull Distribution.
I found online how to make Negative log likelihood for a binomial
distribution (k is the shape parameter, l is the scale parameter and y_true is the current value that the loss function gets):

```
nll = (
        tf.math.lgamma(k) 
        + tf.math.lgamma(y_true + 1)
        - tf.math.lgamma(k + y_true)
        - k * tf.math.log(l)
        - y_true * tf.math.log(1 - l)
    )
```

but I don't know how to calculate the negative log likelihood for a Weibull distribution.

Comment: Well I suppose that it worked ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to take the sum of the log probabilities of this PDF:
[image]

Now, ignoring the part of x<0 (which i hope that your dataset fulfill, otherwise you have chosen the wrong distribution), the transformation is done as follows:

1. you have the product of the probabilities: `prod p(x)`
2. you take the log, so you have `log(prod p(x))`
3. by log properties, becomes `sum log(p(x))`
4. you just substitute `p(x)` with the above formula, and apply the properties of log

Now, your NN should predict both `k` and `lambda` (will call it `l`), supposing that the output layer respect the domain of the parameters,  the loss of a single element is the following:

```
def loss(x,k,l,epsilon=1e-7):
    return tf.math.log(k)-tf.math.log(l) + (tf.math.log(x) - tf.math.log(k)) * (k-1) - tf.pow(x/(k+epsilon), k)
```

And I'm pretty sure you can just add a reduce at the beginning to make it work for multiple prediction:

```
def loss(targets,k_predictions,lambda_predictions,epsilon=1e-7):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.math.log(k_predictions) - tf.math.log(lambda_predictions) + (tf.math.log(targets) - 
        tf.math.log(k_predictions)) * (k_predictions-1) - tf.pow(targets/(k_predictions+epsilon), k_predictions)
    )
```